# Approximation to the ratio of a Gaussian CDF to PDF

Tags: tag-removed, st.statistics, approximation-theory

Johnstone and Silverman (2005) claimed that for large x

$\frac{1-\Phi(x)}{\phi(x)} \approx \frac{1}{x}$

where $\Phi(x)$ and $\phi(x)$ are the CDF and PDF for a normal random variable.

I was able to verify the claim numerically. Q: But how would I show this analytically? This seems like it should be easy, but I can't figure it out. Also, Q: Is there a symbolic logic system (e.g., Mathematica) that can generate these sort of approximations?

Comment: Hint: integration by parts in the integral for the CDF. This is a very standard trick for finding asymptotic approximations for many kinds of integrals.

Comment: @Zen: Ahh, nice trick. Then you generate a power series in $1/x$---the one given by @Robert below. 

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you interpret this as the existence of the limit
$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x(1-\Phi(x))}{\phi(x)}
$$
then it is easy to verify using l'Hopital's rule.

Comment: @Deane: Ahh yes. Easy. I suspected. :( Second derivatives of numerator and denominator do the trick. 

Answer (score 6):

In Maple:

> with(Statistics):
>   Phi:= CDF(Normal(0,1),x): phi:= PDF(Normal(0,1),x):
>   asympt((1-Phi)/phi,x,10);

$\frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x^3} + \frac{3}{x^5} - \frac{15}{x^7}  + \frac{105}{x^9} + O\left(\frac{1}{x^{11}}\right)$

See also http://oeis.org/A001147 for the sequence of coefficients

Comment: @Robert. VERY useful. I must get Maple (or Mathematica). Thx!

Comment: That's a surprisingly simple series expansion. $1*3*5*...*(2n-1)$

Answer (score 4):

If $Y(x)=(1-\Phi(x))/\phi(x)$, it is easy to check that $Y'(x)=xY(x)-1$ and from this anything you like follows by standard methods.

Comment: @Brendan. Then by L'hospital's rule on $Y'(x)$ we get that $\lim_{\infty}Y'(x)=0$ so that $\lim_{\infty}xY(x)=1$ or $Y(x) \approx \frac{1}{x}$ as x becomes large. Thx!

Answer (score 4):

Reproducing a lemma from the classic Feller book, first we can write

$$
(1-3x^{-4})\phi(x)<\phi(x)<(1+x^{-2})\phi(x).
$$

Integrating this from $x$ to $+\infty$, we obtain

$$(x^{-1}-x^{-3})\phi(x)<1-\Phi(x)< x^{-1}\phi(x),$$

so you easily get an approximation rate $x^{-3}\phi(x)$, too.

Comment: Something is wrong here - for example the first line is a little too trivial. Could you please provide the exact reference?

Comment: @domotorp: I don't happen to have Feller's book anywhere around, but I do not see what seems to be a problem. Yes, the first line of inequalities is trivial, but it is only a differential version of the second one.

Comment: The coefficients on the l.h.s. are chosen so that a certain cancellation occurs when you differentiate the l.h.s. of the second chain of inequalities.

Comment: I see, nice trick! What I meant was - what is "Feller's book"? For someone not knowing much about the topic, this does not reveal much...

Comment: @domotorp: W.Feller. An Introduction to Probability Theory and its Applications, Vol I and II

Answer (score 3):

The stated result can be easily obtained by successive applications of integration by parts. We know that
$$
1 - \Phi(x) = \Phi^c(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{x}^{\infty} e^{-t^2/2}dt.
$$ To apply integration by parts, multiply and divide the integrand by
$\frac{1}{t}$ to obtain
$$
\Phi^c(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{x}^{\infty} \frac{1}{t} \left(t e^{-t^2/2}\right)dt
$$
The terms shown in brackets can be integrated to obtain $-e^{-t^2/2}$. Hence, the integral simplifies to
$$
\Phi^c(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{x} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{x}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t^2/2}}{t^2}.
$$
Now we know that

- $\phi(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/2}$ and moreover
- the integral term on the right hand side is always greater than 0, i.e. specifically,
  $$
  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{x}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-t^2/2}}{t^2} \geq 0.
  $$

Hence, combining these observations we find that
$$
\Phi^c(x) \leq \frac{\phi(x)}{x}
$$ or in other words,
$$
\frac{1 - \Phi(x)}{\phi(x)} \leq \frac{1}{x}
$$

Now, you could continue to apply integration by parts again on $\Phi^c(x)$ to obtain a lower bound. More specifically, we obtain
$$
\Phi^c(x) = \phi(x) \left( \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x^3} \right) + \int_{x}^{\infty} 3t^{-4} e^{-t^2/2}dt.
$$ Again, the integral on the right hand side is positive and hence,
$$
\phi(x) \left( \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{x^3} \right) \leq \Phi^c(x).
$$
Combining both these inequalities we find that $\frac{1}{x} - o(x^{-1}) \leq \frac{\Phi^c(x)}{\phi(x)} \leq \frac{1}{x}$. In other words,
$$
\frac{\Phi^c(x)}{\phi(x)} \approx \frac{1}{x}
$$ in the asymptotic limit of $x$.

It turns out that more applications of integration by parts leads to an alternating series which is enveloping. More details can be taken from the textbook by Christopher G Small, *Expansions and asymptotics for statistics*, Monographs on Statistics and Applied Probability 115. Boca Raton, FL: CRC Press, ISBN 978-1-58488-590-0/hbk; 978-1-4200-1102-9/ebook, pp. xiv+343 (2010), [MR2681183](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2681183), [Zbl 1196.62002](https://zbmath.org/1196.62002), which should be available online.